# balls have empty boundary with regard to the $p$-adic norm

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $p$ be prime, $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $r\geq0$. How can I show that the closed ball $D(a,r)$ in $(\mathbb{Q},|\cdot|_p)$ must have an empty boundary (with regard to the topology induced by the [$p$-adic norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_numbers#Analytic_approach))

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

If $r=0$ then $\partial D(a,r)=\{a\}$. Suppose that $r>0$ and $b\in D(a,r)$. Let $c\in D(b,r/2)$. Since $(\mathbb{Q},|\cdot|_p)$ is an ultrametric space, we have $|a-c|_p\le\max\{|a-b|_p,|b-c|_p\}=r$. That is $c\in D(a,r)$. So $D(a,r)$ is a clopen set, that is $\partial D(a,r)=\varnothing$.